# Implement a Look Through in Django

Tags: django

I want to have a Django view that queries the model, and then if it doesn't find anything uses an object to attempt to get the information from the internet.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
def my_view(request, foo):
    try:
        bar = ModelClass.objects.get(property=foo)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        bar = api_object.get(foo)
```

What I want to avoid is:

```
def my_view(request, foo):
    try:
        bar = ModelClass.objects.get(property=foo)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        api_object = ApiObject()
        bar = api_object.get(foo)
```

How do I do this so that I don't have to construct `api_object` each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django idiomatic way to do this is through customizing [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/). So I would do something like

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_or_fetch(self, property):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        try:
            return queryset.model.get(property=property)
        except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            return api_object.get(property)

class ModelClass(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()


# in your view
bar = ModelClass.objects.get_or_fetch(property=foo)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question wasn't clear. How do I do this so that `api_object` is only created once at startup, and then only lives in the namespace of my view/manager?

Comment: I guess that I could get around this by making `api_object` a property of `MyManager` though.

Comment: @Batman well that works. You can also chuck it in any file that Django loads on start time. It depends on your taste to be honest but making it a property of the manager is fair.